# formatted date and time from postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, date

I am using server time for one of my process. For that I am taking date and time using postgresql. The time format I want is 2 digit day,month,hour,minute,second and 4 digit year (eg: 05/01/2015 16:05:30). I am using 
`SELECT to_char(now()::timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` 
 I want to make sure that the number of digits for each will be as like I want. Because its very important for my processing. I have refered the following link [Link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html). There it is saying, day of month (01-31) for `DD`'s decription. Is there any possibility to get day as `1` instide of `01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel safe.

The table ad your link (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)
is right.

Numbers in date converted with to_char, are 0 padded.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to get day as `1` instide of `01`

You can use regular expression to remove leading `0`:

```
select regexp_replace(to_char(now()::timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '^0(\d)', '\1', 'g');
```